# SignalR Transports when using the .NET Client

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I am thinking about using SignalR in some WCF and WPF applications.

In reading about SignalR I understand it supports 4 different transport types:

- WebSocket
- Server Sent Events
- Forever Frame
- Ajax Long Polling

**If I have a WPF or WCF application using the SignalR .net client talking to a normal SignalR server (like the SignalR sample), which one of these transport types are used?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SignalR .NET client supports up to 3 transports:

1. WebSockets (.NET 4.5 only)

   Version 2.2.0 of the SignalR client will also support the WebSocket transport in [universal Windows apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx).
2. Server-sent events
3. Long polling

There is also the default auto transport that will try to use the best transport available. For example, it will initially try to start a connection using WebSockets, but if that fails, the it will try to use server-sent events next and then long polling.

The .NET client will never try to use the forever frame transport because that transport is very similar to server-sent events. The main difference between the two transports is that the forever frame transport wraps its payload in HTML to support older browsers which load the payload using an iframe.

You can learn more about the .NET client and the provided transports in [this guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#transport).